# call of [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].types returns always UIUserNotificationTypeNone

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I need to check if user have enabled push notifications in Settings. For this I use this code:

```
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
        // NO
    }
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
        UIUserNotificationSettings *noticationSettings =     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
        if (!noticationSettings || (noticationSettings.types ==   UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
            NSLog(@"NO");
            // here it does not work, I enabled push notifications
            // in settings and noticationSettings.types returns UIUserNotificationTypeNone
            // NO
        } else {
            NSLog(@"YES");
            // YES
        }
    }
```

but problem is that noticationSettings.types returns alwyas UIUserNotificationTypeNone, regardless whether are push notifications enabled in Settings or not.

As you can see on the picture, I have enabled push notifications, but noticationSettings.types returns me UIUserNotificationTypeNone, can anybody tell me where could be the problem? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you actually register for push notifications by calling `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:`? Are push notifications enabled in your provisioning profile? Just enabling push notifications in settings is really not enough to start receiving push notifications.

Comment: Yes, I call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeNone categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];` and after that is called method `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`. And thing is that I recieve push notifications, but that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].types` returns me `UIUserNotificationTypeNone`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates that you did not call `registerUserNotificationSettings` with `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` or `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` or `UIUserNotificationTypeAlert`.

Try the following:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                     |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                     |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];

UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Comment: I just realized the error, it was because I was registering notifications for types `UIUserNotificationTypeNone`, so `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].types` was returning always `UIUserNotificationTypeNone`, regardless if push notifications was enabled or not. When I changed registration to all types, it returns me `UIUserNotificationTypeNone` only when push notifications are disabled in settings - and that's what I need. Thank you for pointing me out.